# How to add a bottom bar to a slidePaneLayout

Tags: android

How to add a bottom bar to a slidePaneLayout?.

Could you please help me on this,

I need a bottom bar of **height = 50dp** and **width = fill_parent**. which contains 3 small buttons/icons.

At the bottom of a **SlidePaneLayout**

Answer (score 0):

Put the **SlidingPaneLayout** inside a **RelativeLayout** and then add your suitable bottom bar **RelativeLayout** just after the **SlidingPaneLayout**

And then specify the below properties

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Complete **xml code** is pasted below for reference.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/slidingpanelayout">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#8B8989"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_leftpane">
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#99CC32"
              android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_rightpane">
    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:text="BottomBar" >

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```